# Scrollable Div with -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch inside iFrame not working in iOS 10 mobile Safari

Tags: ios, css, iframe, scroll, mobile-safari

I have an **iFrame that contains a div** that should be scrollable (just the div, not the whole iFrame). This works now fine in most browsers, but not in iOS 10 (tested with iPhone 7), where nothing is moveable:
https://codepen.io/arichter83/full/OJLNjey

### Fixes outside the iFrame

When adding the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;overflow-y:scroll;height:300px` to the iFrame itself it works: https://codepen.io/arichter83/full/xxKVpbL

But this seems to be a **bug of iOS 10**, because it also works if adding those parameters to an other div besides the iFrame: https://codepen.io/arichter83/full/PoYNEoX

### Fixes inside the iFrame

So but actually my situation is, that I **can't control the content outside the iFrame**, so does anybody knows a **workaround**?

I tried:

1. Switching to `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:auto;`
2. Add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` or `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to the `body`

Answer (score 1):

In the past while dealing with iOS, I've forced hardware acceleration on the body to deal with scrolling issues.

```
body { 
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Didn't have enough points to add a comment - figured this might help.

Comment: Thank you, yes that helped me also in the past with similar situations, but didn't help here!

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, but it's hacky:

```js
function resetScroller() {
  scroller = document.getElementById('scroller')
  scroller.style.webkitOverflowScrolling = 'auto'
  scroller.style.display = 'none'
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    scroller.style.display = 'block'
  }, 0)
}
```

Change the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;`, hide the element and show it again after a bit.

This can be done only for iOS 10 with the following condition:

```
const ios_version = window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod).* OS ([0-9]+)/)[2] as unknown as number
if(ios_version > 0 && ios_version <= 10) {
  ...
}
```

I included a button in the iFrame content so it can be tested: https://codepen.io/arichter83/full/OJLNjey